# Disable alt-tab animation on KDE plasma

Tags: kde-plasma-5

KDE does this fade effect on alt-tab that is mega-slow on my craptop. How can I disable it? I see nothing in the desktop effects settings.

Comment: "Craptops" work better with less demanding desktop environments like the ones you have in Xubuntu and Lubuntu ;) This is an alternative way of saying that if that animation is "mega-slow" then KDE is too much for that hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it under Compositor > Animation speed.

Answer (score 1):

With KDE Plasma Version 5.24.7 this is still in the setting but now under `Workspace Behavior -> General Behavior -> Animation speed`